# NewtonSoft.Json Parse json callback

Tags: c#, json

I have this callback

```
{
  "status": "200",
  "name": "Something Here",
  "serverversion": "v1.2.4.1",
  "tshockversion": {
    "Major": 4,
    "Minor": 2,
    "Build": 4,
    "Revision": 128,
    "MajorRevision": 0,
    "MinorRevision": 128
  },
  "port": 7777,
  "playercount": 27,
  "maxplayers": 60,
  "world": "Something Here",
  "uptime": "0.05:14:08",
  "serverpassword": false
}
```

Windows Form Application, so i need to write on label1 like this: 27 from 60.
Help me, please.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Can you please add some clarity to your question? For example, what is "label1"? It's unclear how you want to edit your JSON object. Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) topic or take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks and good luck!

Comment: Okay, so that's easy enough to do either with LINQ to JSON or converting to a strongly-typed object. What have you tried and what happened? There's no *question* here...

Comment: That's a json response, not a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to parse a json response and display the text playercount + " from " + maxplayers on a label. yes?

First you need a strongly typed class. Use a tool like [json2sharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to define the class and save it to your project.

```
public class Tshockversion
{
    public int Major { get; set; }
    public int Minor { get; set; }
    public int Build { get; set; }
    public int Revision { get; set; }
    public int MajorRevision { get; set; }
    public int MinorRevision { get; set; }
}

public class JsonResponse
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string serverversion { get; set; }
    public Tshockversion tshockversion { get; set; }
    public int port { get; set; }
    public int playercount { get; set; }
    public int maxplayers { get; set; }
    public string world { get; set; }
    public string uptime { get; set; }
    public bool serverpassword { get; set; }
}
```

then, you can convert the json string and update your label

```
JsonResponse data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(json);
label1.Content = data.playercount + " from " + data.maxplayers
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not simply follow the manual?

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

You may create a class, deserialize it and then you can access the properties of the deserialized object from the response you've got.

Comment: You help me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `json_response` is a `string` containing the [text from OP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28327708/1020470) ...

```
string json_response = {
  "status": "200",
  "name": "Something Here",
  "serverversion": "v1.2.4.1",
  "tshockversion": {
    "Major": 4,
    "Minor": 2,
    "Build": 4,
    "Revision": 128,
    "MajorRevision": 0,
    "MinorRevision": 128
  },
  "port": 7777,
  "playercount": 27,
  "maxplayers": 60,
  "world": "Something Here",
  "uptime": "0.05:14:08",
  "serverpassword": false
}
```

... then using [`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq.htm) [`JToken.Parse() Method`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse.htm) which lets you parse either [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) or [`JArray`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) objects ...

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

... you can try this ...

```
JObject data = (JObject)JToken.Parse(json_response);
label1.Content = data["playercount"].ToString() + " from " +
                 data["maxplayers"].ToString();
```

### References

1. [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)
2. [Json.NET Documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)
3. [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)
4. [Parsing JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParsingLINQtoJSON.htm)
5. [Querying JSON with LINQ](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)
6. [`JToken.Item` Property](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Item.htm)
7. [`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq` Namespace](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq.htm)

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried:

```
....
"uptime": "0.05:14:08",
"serverpassword": false,
"label1" : function(){return playercount + ' from ' + maxplayers;}
}
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: this is c# and JSON does not have functions.